# "Flipping bits" Python implementation

Tags: python, programming-challenge, python-2.x, bitwise

Problem Statement

> You will be given a list of 32 bits unsigned integers. You are required to output the list of the unsigned integers you get by flipping bits in its binary representation (i.e. unset bits must be set, and set bits must be unset).

Input Format

> The first line of the input contains the list size T, which is followed by T lines, each line having an integer from the list.

Constraints

> \$1≤T≤100\$
>
> \$0≤integer<2^{32}\$

Output Format

> Output one line per element from the list with the requested result.

Solution

```
for _ in range(int(raw_input())):
    N = int(raw_input())
    N = N & 0xffffffff # 32 bit representation
    print N ^ 0xffffffff
```

Hint: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16745422/4260745

Comment: This code works fine for me. Have it here on ideone too: http://ideone.com/zvLAXx

Answer (score 2):

There's not much to review; that said, the input is guaranteed to be
between zero and \$2^{32}\$, so there is no point to the `N & 0xffffffff` really.  Also the `print` statement would be more upwards
compatible with Python 3 if it was used like a function,
i.e. `print(...)`.

Comment: No! It doesn't work without converting it to 32bit. Please check once.